# Kalman-filter with 100 data samples containing noise

Tags: kalman-filter, pykalman

If I have a series of observations of say 100 samples of x and y.
Is this enough to predict the 101th y corresponding to a x value?Can I use some part of this data of 100 samples to update some values(Considering that noise exists and some data might be corrupt) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about code.

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow is directed at coding - so if you have code that you expect to work, and it doesn't, you should post it with your question.

A Kalman filter can help in the problem you describe if you have a model for the dependence of y on x.  So, for example, if your model is that:
y = a * x + b + Gaussian noise, then the Kalman filter is one way to estimate 'a' and 'b', which then allow you to predict the 101'st y from the 101'st x.